# What's the difference between a MAUI class library and a normal class library?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, class-library

As far as I can tell a MAUI Class Library is a class library in .NET 6, where you can inject platform specific code. But is there really any other difference between a MAUI library and a .NET 6 library? Are they interchangeable if you leave out the platform code?

Comment: The only differene I know is MAUI specific conditional compilation

Answer (score 14):

The only difference is that it has the multi-targeting already built-in. Meaning that the .NET MAUI class library will already have a Platforms folder with the different platforms inside of that and you can put your platform specific code in there.

That is also described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting

If you're really sure you don't need any platform specifics you can also use a regular class library. If you do run into something that requires you to use platform-specific code or you want to have more control over the naming conventions etc. You can still follow the documentation that is linked above.

Comment: I highly doubt that a regular class library now also has the platforms folder. What is more convenient is totally up to you and how you like to work with multi-targeting. Both ways end up with the exact same working.