# Xamarin Forms migration to .NETMaui

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have the following solution built in Xamarin Forms that I want to migrate. I'm doing it manually, so for now all the c# .NET Standard projects I already migrated them by creating .NET MAUI Class Library projects and then moved the code from the old one to this one and all those are compiling perfect.

My question is about those projects that I marked with green in the image. What type of project should I create so I move the old code into this one?

[image]

I know that besides also moving code I need to perform what it says here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/forms-projects#namespace-changes

That basically is:

- Update your project file to be SDK-style.
- Update namespaces.
- Address any API changes.
- Configure .NET MAUI.
- Upgrade or replace incompatible dependencies with .NET 6+ versions.
- Compile and test your app.

Comment: Did you out the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant)?

Comment: Platform-dependent classes should go to the main MAUI-project, `platforms` folder, and then to relevant sub-folder which name is relevant to the platform. All Xamarin-plugins should be replaced to MAUI alternatives.

Comment: You can try to convert the xamarin.android class library to the .net android class library and put it in the Platforms/Android folder. And the ios is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A Maui class library includes "multi-targetting".

This means that instead of separate projects `Library1`, `Library1.Android`, `Library1.iOS`, make a single Maui class library `Library1`. The Android code belongs in folder `Platforms/Android` of `Library1`. Similar for iOS. Use Maui class library project template to get correct set up.

This may lead to other code refactoring. "partial classes" are often used to combine cross-platform code with corresponding platform-specific code.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74098246/199364, which mentions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting